# Cannot import ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I learning Java Spring Framework by listening to
the "Spring & Hibernate for Beginners" udemy course.
I struggled while trying to
import **org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**;

Eclipse shows me the error:
***ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved***

The author of the course to which I'm listening is still not involving Maven
(and pom.xml) because he is concentrating on
"pure" Java and Spring in his course,
so please don't direct me to use Maven for organizing the project.

I added all jars from **spring-framework-5.0.2.RELEASE-dist** to my projects buildpath.

The funny thing is that when i do CTRL+Shift+O Eclipse automatically imports
the **org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** package,
but it shows error in import line (red line under **org**)
and shows an error in my main function
on the line where I try to use context as:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Please help.

Comment: That class path seems wrong.  I don't know this specific framework but a class path usually refers to a path on your file system where needed Jar files can be found.  E.g. `"C:/Users/MyName/develop/udemy/proj/lib/spring-framework-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar"`

Comment: Saying that you have a red line somewhere is much too vague. Tell us what you are doing (compiling? running?), how precisely you're doing it, and which complete and exact error you get.

Comment: Do you specifically have `spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar` on your buildpath? What about other spring classes? For example can you import `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`?

Comment: I have spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar on my buildpath, and yes, it is giving me the error for FileSystemXmlApplicationContext. I tried for both 5.0.2 and 5.0.9 versions of jars, and errors are same.

Comment: Build path != class path.  They're two different things.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just want to share that Ш have found a solution to my problem.
My execution environment JRE was set to be JAVA SE 10. After I change it to be JAVA SE 1.8 everything started working, and no errors are showing now.

I do it like this:

1. Right click on your project, then open Properties
2. Java build path
3. Click on Add Library
4. Choose JRE system library
5. Click on environments and choose JAVA SE 1.8
6. After that, I removed JAVA SE 10 from my build path and everything becomes right.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the module-info.java file in your project, It's only used if you're using Java's built-in module system.

Hope that helps:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following:
a. right click the project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (tab)

Make sure spring-context jar is present and there is only one version of it.

If that is the case, try closing and reopening the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in intelliJ by doing the following:

1. File > Project Structure
2. Modules
3. Dependencies Tab
4. Click (+) button
5. Add JARs or Directories
6. Navigate to the correct .jar to import ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Because I have been using maven in the past, I already had the .jar file downloaded. My .jar file was at the following location on my drive:

1. home folder
2. Unhide hidden folders
3. .m2 folder
4. repository > org > springframework > spring-context > 5.2.4 RELEASE
5. Select .jar file

I also had to import the "spring-beans" and "spring-core" libraries to get the code to run in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Right Click your Project --> move mouse to "Build Path" tab
Step 2: Choice "Configure Build Path"
Step 3: on tab "Libraries" and click "Classpath". If "Classpath" is empty, it mean you still not add .jar and can't import ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.
How to:

1. create a new folder equal level src. i suggest name folder is "lib".
2. Download .jar file and copy to folder lib.
3. Follow step 3 above and click "Add jar" on right tab and choice .jar file on "lib" folder.
4. Finish and enjoy!